# C++ map with value as list, add and remove elements from list

Tags: c++, list, dictionary

I have a unordered_map with key as string and value as list of string. I am able to figure out how to add elements to the list (which is a value to a specific key in the unordered map). What I am not able to figure out is how to remove elements from the same list.

Key parts of the code are:

Matrix is a basically imitating a pair of src and dest. Where I am trying to organize it to map where key is a unique src and the dest is collected in the value list.

Ex: [[A,B],[A,c]] -> {A:[B,C]}

```
vector<vector<string>>& matrix; 
unordered_map<string, list<string>> um;

for (vector<string> mat: matrix) {
  src = mat[0];
  dst = mat[1];

  if (um.find(src) == um.end()) {
    um[src] = list<string>();
  }
  um[src].push_back(dst);
}
```

Above code seems to work as desired

To delete this is what I am doing

The unordered map can be something like this

```
{
A:[B,C],
C: [B],
B: [A,C]
}
```

The logic for below snippet is to start with A, pop B from list as value for key A. Use B, which is pop'ed from A's value list and find list which is value for key B and pop first element from it. Which happens to be A. So now use A as key to find the its value list and pop the next un-pop'ed element C, but to my surprise although I tried to pop B from list of key A when its still there.
Map is essentially a adjacency matrix of a cyclic graph where I am trying to delete/remove the edges one by one, but my question is specific to the syntax/code here.

```
string starting_src_key = "A";
string temp_str;
list<string> &templ = um[starting_src_key];
while(!templ.empty()) {
   temp_str = templ.front();
   cout << "\n" << temp_str;
   templ.pop_front();
   templ = um[temp_res];
}
```

I have tried various things like instead of `&templ` as variable I tried with just `templ` too (no `&` sign) but that didn't work either.

I am new to C++ so trying to understand a bit about map and list.

Comment: You don't need the `um.find` check, since `um[src]` will add an element if one does not exist.

Comment: The deletion part doesn't work. Part where I am doing templ.pop_front()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot re-seat a reference, so `templ = um[temp_res];` doesn't do what you expect. Use a pointer instead.

```
list<string> * templ = & um[starting_src_key];
while(!templ -> empty()) {
   temp_str = templ -> front();
   cout << "\n" << temp_str;
   templ -> pop_front();
   templ = & um[temp_res];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So if I had done um[temp_res].pop_front(); - this would have also done the trick right?

Comment: Yes this will work but could be wasteful,  since `um[temp_res]` is evaluated several times.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you meant by "evaluated several times". Can you pls elaborate?

Comment: You need to so something like `while(!um[key].empty()) { key = um[key].pop_front(); }` so there are at least two calls to `um[key]`.

Comment: Ah! Now I see what you mean. Thanks